# Microsoft IIS : Recognize the current logged user

Tags: iis, asp-classic

The intranet of my company is able to get the login of the current Windows session. The method is cross-browser (it works in IE, Chrome, Firefox...)

For example : If I open a Windows session (username : toto) the intranet is able to say "Hello Toto"

The username logged is a local information (client-side) but the server can access to it... Nothing in the HTTP query, no cookies...

The intranet is powered by ASP on a Microsoft IIS 6.0 server. When I look the code, this is how the server get the information :

```
uid = session("u_id")
strsql = "select ntlogon from user_group where id = " & uid
set rst = conn.Execute(strsql)
if not isnull(rst("ntlogon")) then
    ntlogon = rst("ntlogon")
end if
```

The server puts an uid in the session and a SQL query retrieves the username.

How the server can know that ? And is it possible to have the same information on a LAMP stack ?

Thank you

Comment: " this is how the server get the information" - no, you're showing us how the server *uses* this information. How it *gets* the information is in a piece of code you've not shown us, where it *sets* `session("u_id")`

Comment: It's the only ASP lines executed to render the page, nothing before. I think it's the server which set the session variable "u_uid". Thank's

Comment: No, in classic ASP, the way to obtain the user name was to access [`Request.ServerVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx) for `REMOTE_USER`

Comment: "REMOTE_USER" works only if the browser send the appropriate informations over HTTP. It's not the case in this situation

Comment: Well then, I guess you've got some kind of crazy, custom, setup that we can't possibly help tell you about, because that's the standard way it works.

Comment: If there is a folder or file in IIS that the Anonymous Internet user account of IIS (IUSR_[machinename]) has no or insufficient rights to, IIS will show an NT domain login prompt. If the user logs in, the request.servervariable REMOTE USER is set.

Comment: what do you mean by "open a Windows session"?

Comment: Look in a file called "global.asa" most likely you will find the code populating the session in there.